# EF Code-first MVC: Should I add fields to the default AspNetUsers table or create another 'UserInfo' table that relates to the AspNetUsers table?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, registration

I am making a simple MVC application using code first entity framework. I'm trying to use the built in user registration/login. It provides me the default AccountController and [ASP User tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAE0V.png).

My other entities are Players, Games, and Tournaments:

```
public class Player
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<Game> Games { get; set; }
    public List<Tournament> Tournaments { get; set; }
}

public class Game
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Player> Players { get; set; }
    public List<Tournament> Tournaments { get; set; } 
}

 public class Tournament
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Player> Players { get; set; }
    public List<Game> Games { get; set; }

}
```

EF provides [these tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGtNh.png).

Everyone who logs in is a player. I want each player to have a password and username. Should I remove my `Players` table and add the `Player` properties to the provided `User` class and `AspNetUsers` table? Or should I use a foreign-key to create a relationship between the `Players` table and the `AspNetUsers` table?

Are either or both of those options possible/preferable?

Also just a note, there will be additional properties in the Players, Games, and Tournaments classes; I was just starting with the basics.

Thank you very much for your time. Let me know if I am being unclear or if you need any additional information.

EDIT:
Just found this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx

It shows something like both methods I described above. What is the advantage of adding a new UserInfo table vs. adding fields to the existing table?

Comment: If the info in the `Player` class is required to sign up, then it should be part of the `User` table

Answer (score 0):

I would add this property to the player table:

```
public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
```

where ApplicationUser is the table that was given out of the box by Visual Studio.
The ApplicationUser uses identity so when user creates a new player, have the playerController's Create action to set the user id of the user to the player id in the player table:

```
var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
Player.PlayerId = userId;
```

Answer (score -1):

Add properties to ApplicationUser class. Also I suggest you to rename it to Player, so code will better match domain language.

Comment: Thank you very much for reaching out. I tried to add properties to ApplicationUser `FirstName` and `LastName` are not ending up in my database after migrations and I am getting a `500 Internal Server Error` when trying to register a user with a first name and last name. [I made a post about it here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31034931/http-post-resulting-in-500-internal-server-error-with-c-sharp-mvc-after-addin). Please let me know if you have any ideas as to what might be causing this. Thank you for your time

Comment: @ranquild answer is totally useless to the OP.